# Why does conjugate gradient work with this nonsymmetric preconditioner?

Tags: preconditioning, conjugate-gradient, krylov-method, symmetry

In [this previous thread](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/10883/1502) the following multiplicative way to combine symmetric preconditioners $P_1$ and $P_2$ for the symmetric system $Ax=b$ was suggested:
\begin{align}
P_\text{combo}^{-1} :=& P_1^{-1} + P_2^{-1}(I - A P_1^{-1})\\
=&P_1^{-1} + P_2^{-1} - P_2^{-1} A P_1^{-1}.
\end{align}

This combined preconditioner is not symmetric. However, I have tried using it in conjugate gradient anyways in several different contexts, and the method always seems to converge just fine. Why is this?

---

**Example 1:** Random matrices.

```
% Testing multiplicative combination of preconditioners
n = 500;
[U,S,~] = svd(randn(n,n)); A = U*S*U';
[W1,S1,~] = svd(randn(n,n)); noise1 = W1*S1*W1';
[W2,S2,~] = svd(randn(n,n)); noise2 = W2*S2*W2';
P1 = A + 0.5 * noise1;
P2 = A + 0.5 * noise2;

solve_P = @(x) P1\x + P2\x - P2\(A*(P1\x));

b = randn(n,1);
x_true = A\b;
pcg(A,b,1e-6,n);
pcg(A,b,1e-6,n,P1);
x = pcg(A,b,1e-6,n,solve_P);
norm(x_true - x)/norm(x_true)
```

Here's the output I get:

```
pcg converged at iteration 127 to a solution with relative residual 9.9e-07.
pcg converged at iteration 62 to a solution with relative residual 6.8e-07.
pcg converged at iteration 51 to a solution with relative residual 8.1e-07.
relative error= 4.23e-07
```

---

**Example 2:** Combining multigrid with incomplete cholesky for solving the Poisson equation.

```
n = 50; N = n^2;
A = gallery('poisson',n); %Laplacian on n-by-n grid, zero dirichlet BC

L = ichol(A);
solve_P1 = @(x) L'\(L\x);
% Combinatorial multigrid: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jkoutis/cmg.html
solve_P2 = cmg_sdd(A); 

solve_P = @(x) solve_P1(x) + solve_P2(x) - solve_P1(A*solve_P2(x));

b = randn(N,1);
x_true = A\b;
pcg(A,b,1e-6,N);
pcg(A,b,1e-6,N,solve_P1);
pcg(A,b,1e-6,N,solve_P2);
x = pcg(A,b,1e-6,N,solve_P);
disp(['relative error= ', num2str(norm(x_true - x)/norm(x_true),3)])
```

For this I get the results:

```
pcg converged at iteration 131 to a solution with relative residual 8.4e-07.
pcg converged at iteration 44 to a solution with relative residual 6e-07.
pcg converged at iteration 19 to a solution with relative residual 7e-07.
pcg converged at iteration 12 to a solution with relative residual 4.7e-07.
relative error= 5.2e-07
```

---

Notes:

- I've also seen the same qualitative behavior on matrices arising in more complicated/realistic situations.
- Given an incorrect solution to $Ax=b$, the error $e$ and the residual $r$ are related by the error equation $Ae=r$. One can view this combo preconditioner as approximately solving the original equation using $P_1$ instead of $A$, then approximately solving the error equation with $P_2$ instead of $A$, then adding the approximate error back to correct the original approximate solution.

Comment: In your first formula, I think there should be no $x$.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thanks, that was a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

In short, orthogonalization of the Krylov vectors occurs with respect to the operator, but not with respect to the preconditioner.

Alright, so say we want to solve $Ax=b$ with preconditioner $B$.  the preconditioned-CG iteration is basically:

\begin{align*}
\hat{v}_1=\tilde{v}_1 =& Bb\\
v_1 =& \tilde{v}_1 / c_1\\
\\
\hat{v}_i =& BAv_{i-1}\\
\tilde{v}_i=&\hat{v}_i-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} \langle Av_k,\hat{v}_i\rangle v_k\\
v_i =& \tilde{v}_i/c_i\\
c_i =& \sqrt{\langle \tilde{v}_i,\tilde{v}_i\rangle}
\end{align*}
In other words

- $\hat{v}_i$ - New Krylov vector
- $\tilde{v}_i$ - Orthgonalized Krylov vector
- $v_i$ - Normalized Krylov vector

Now, what's interesting from this is that we get a number of properties.  The two that really matter for you are

1. $\textrm{span}\{v_i\}_{i=1}^m = \textrm{span}\{(BA)^{i-1}(Bb)\}_{i=1}^m$
2. $V^TAV = I$

The first property follows from how $\hat{v}_i$ is generated.  We're subtracting things from it and normalizing, but we're basically just getting a bunch of $BAv_{i-1}$ where $v_1$ is a scaling of $Bb$.  The second property follows from $\tilde{v}_i$.  Here, we do *not* use $B$ in the orthogonalization.  Orthogonalization depends purely on $A$ being symmetric positive definite.

Now, say we want to solve the system $Ax=b$.  If we choose $x$ in our Krylov space, we solve for $\beta$ in
$$
AV\beta = b
$$
However, this is probably overdetermined.  Hence, we solve the normal equations, so that
$$
V^TAV\beta = V^Tb
$$
From above, we know that $V^TAV=I$, so we really have that
$$
\beta = V^Tb
$$
or that
$$
x = VV^Tb.
$$
Note, this holds regardless of the preconditioner $B$.  In fact, we could take random vectors and $A$-orthogonalize them against each other and the same would hold.  Really, the only thing that $B$ affects is the Krylov space.  As long as $B$ helps cluster the eigenvalues of $A$, the algorithm performs well.  Though, if $B$ is nonsymmetric, we may have to look at something like the pseudospectra to figure that out.  I'm not entirely sure.  Mostly, cluster the spectra.

Do we lose anything with a nonsymmetric $B$?  Probably.  Normally, in CG, we have properties like $\langle Br_i,r_j\rangle = 0$ for all $i\neq j$.  I'm pretty sure that no longer holds.  Also, we normally have $\langle BAv_i,Av_j\rangle=0$ for $|i-j|\geq 2$.  That may or may not hold.  Really, any result that has $B$ I'd be suspicious of.

Anyway, I'm pretty sure it's possible to code CG in a way that'd break everything with a nonsymmetric $B$.  However, if we code it using the equations above, there's nothing that really prohibits it from working with a nonsymmetric $B$.  I do it all the time and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Read http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877050915010492 "Nonsymmetric Preconditioning for Conjugate Gradient and Steepest Descent Methods"

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! Answers should not just contain a link, since these can go away at any time or -- as in this case -- bounce off a paywall. Could you summarize the contents of this paper? Otherwise this is more of a comment than an answer.